# Shouldn't Master Roshi have been disqualified for using Containment Wave?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In the Tournament of Power, one of the rules that is established is that no items are allowed. So shouldn't Master Roshi have been disqualified? Using Containment Wave requires you to have a vessel or type of container to seal the presence away, so I'm not understanding why he is still in the Tournament.

Comment: He should have been yes, infact it was even mentioned that he should be disqualified, but One-chan said it was cool, so he’s not.

Answer (score -1):

Technically yes, Roshi should be disqualified without prejudice for using items/weapons, but for the sake of the plot story, this has been disregard by the author as if the audience is as gullible as he thought. Instead of giving a broad general statement, the Dragon Balls Super authors should have specified their rules to "no offensive weapons allowed" in which this will rule out Roshi use of containment wave as it will be a defensive type of weapon.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Movies and TV SE. About what you said above, **this has been disregard by the author as if audience are as gullible as he thought** , If you have a reference/valid source to back this up, then this'll be a better answer